# Windows 8 shared-folder permissions for different accounts on different computers

Tags: windows-8, permissions, network-shares

I have `ComputerA` with account `A@outlook.com` and `ComputerB` with account `B@hotmail.com`.

`ComputerA` and `ComputerB` have a few shared folders and I would like for them to be accessible by both `A@outlook.com` and `B@hotmail.com`.

How can I get `ComputerA` to recognize `B@hotmail.com` and `ComputerB` to recognise `A@outlook.com` in the *Select Users or Groups* permissions dialog?

This is a home network, so there is no domain-based environment. Each computer only shows it's name as a *location*.

Answer (score 0):

Add the accounts to the credential manager:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon

http://www.howtogeek.com/106906/how-to-add-credentials-to-the-windows-credential-manager-vault/

[image]

When you now connect to the other PC, Windows uses the username / password.

Comment: Windows 8 accounts seem to not work properly with credentials. Windows 7 accounts work fine. In the end, I gave up and changed the permissions of all the folders to the `HomeUsers` group